# Force the ASP.NET page lifecycle to go forward

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, lifecycle, page-lifecycle

Ok, so I am working on a custom framework above the .NET framework, and some instructions are not written / called at the good places.
For example, a postback is done on the same page. Then, a Response.redirect occurs right within the page_load; but at this point, the new values of the controls of the page are not yet handled, so they get lost...

Therefore, I wanted to know whether it was possible to force the pagelife_cycle to go forward before the call to response.redirect, so that I can get the right values.

I can't just make that call in another function, because the page I am working on is called by many web applications (about 1-2k), and it would completely change their behaviour, which is not acceptable!

Is that even possible?

Comment: You can get the values before the Page_Load, but if in the page load is a redirect based on some conditions, you'll loose the event handlers, which performs after the Page_Load handler

Comment: @AdrianIftode, I am not sure of what you are saying. It seems to me that the new values appear from the LoadComplete event. And as the Redirection happens before that, I can't get the new values

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx See a bit the second image and the Load PostBack Data section. Before the Load event of the page is raised, a textbox is already initialized. You can catch the value by overriding OnPreLoad or by adding a handler at PreLoad event.

Comment: Post this as an answer, so that I can accept it if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See a bit the second image and the [Load PostBack Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) section. Before the Load event of the page is raised, a textbox is already initialized. You can catch the value by overriding OnPreLoad or by adding a handler at PreLoad event.